# Electrostatic ion cyclotron waves

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, plasma-physics

On page 102 of the 3rd edition of F.Chen's *introduction to plasma physics and controlled fusion*, he discusses the phenomenon of an ion acoustic wave propagating at right angles to a magnetic field $\mathbf{B}_0$ as shown in the diagram below:

[image]

He mentions that it is unrealistic for $\mathbf{k}$ to be perpendicular to $\mathbf{B}_0$ and it is better to let $\mathbf{k}$ be *almost* perpendicular to $\mathbf{B}_0$ as shown in the diagram above.

He proceeds to mention that since the angle is small, when analyzing the motion of IONS, it suffices to take $\mathbf{E} = E \mathbf{e}_x$ and $\mathbf{k} = k \mathbf{e}_x$, the reason for this is because $k_z$ is small, and the inertia of the ions pretty much guarantees that motion in the $z$ direction is negligible.

However, this argument does not WORK for ELECTRONS because there is a big difference between $\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta = 0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta << 1$

Chen mentions that in the context of electrons, if $\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta = 0$, then:

> **Statement 1:**
> The electrons have such a small Lamor radii that they cannot move in the $x$ direction to preserve charge neutrality; all that the $\mathbf{E}$ field does is make them drift back and forth in the $y$ direction

Chen also mentions that:

> **Statement 2:** The critical angle $\chi = \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta$ is proportional to the ratio of ion to electron parallel velocities:
> $$
> \chi \approx \sqrt{\frac{m_e}{m_i}}
> $$

(a) In statement 1, how does the small Larmor radii of the electron restrict the motion of electrons in the $x$ direction to preserve charge neutrality? It seems to me that it would be better to argue that because the Larmor radii is small, we can ignore the Larmor gyration in the $x$ direction and only focus on the $y$ direction due to the presence of an $\mathbf{E} \times \mathbf{B_0}$ drift.

(b) In statement 2, Chen does not provide any justification as to how he arrives at this conclusion regarding the angle being proportional to that ratio, how does he arrive at this? Even if I take it for granted, to reach the desired expression, I require:
$$
\frac{1}{2}m_e v_{e \parallel}^2 = E_\parallel  = \frac{1}{2}m_i v_{i \parallel}^2 
$$

In order for:
$$
\chi \approx \frac{v_{e \parallel}}{v_{i \parallel}} \approx \sqrt{\frac{m_e}{m_i}}
$$

Again, the fact that the two kinetic energies are equal are not justified

Comment: So I think there is some confusion here.  An oblique ion acoustic wave is not synonymous with an electrostatic ion cyclotron wave (in two-fluid theory, the branch of the slow mode can merge with the ES ICW).  As an aside, I really think Chen's book is one of the worst plasma physics books out there.  It's riddled with mistakes and really bad examples that lead to all sorts of confusion and misunderstandings of how plasmas behave.  A much better and more accurate book is the one by Gurnett and Bhattacharjee.

Comment: @honeste_vivere thank you! I think i will switch to the textbook you suggested. Do you suggest I start  from the beginning or can i jump to chapter 4 in the book by Gurnett and Bhattacharjee?

Comment: That depends on your level of competence.  You may want to glance at the first chapter just to get familiar with the notation as I think it uses a different set of symbols than Chen does.

Comment: @honeste_vivere thank you!